# The average time taken for a random walk to leave an interval is finite

Tags: probability-theory

A problem set I have defines $X_n$ as a random walk on $\mathbb Z$ which increases or decreases by $1$ at each stage with probability $\frac 1 2$, and $T$ as the first time at which the process hits either $-a$ or $b$, $a, b\in \mathbb N$. After asking for the Doob decomposition $X^2 + N + A$ of $X^2$ (for which I get $A_n = n$), it asks:

> By applying a stopping time theorem to $N$, show that $T$ is integrable.

If I could use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) theorem then I would have $E(N_T)=E(X_T^2-T)=0$, and $X_T^2$ is bounded so $E(T)$ must be finite. But the only condition that seems to apply involves $N$ being bounded, which I don't think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $X_n^2-n$ is a martingale, and therefore the stopped process $X_{T \wedge n}^2-T\wedge n$ is also martingale.

Thus $E[X_{T \wedge n}^2 -T \wedge n]=0$, so that $E[T\wedge n] = E[X_{T \wedge n}^2] \leq \max(a,b)^2$ for all $n$. Here the final inequality follows from the fact that $|X_{T \wedge n}| \leq \max(a,b)$.

By the monotone convergence theorem, it follows that $E[T] = \lim_{n \to \infty} E[T \wedge n] \leq \max(a,b)^2$.